"Ignore tag" button is missing as of today
I just went to ignore a tag but the Ignore tag button is missing from the popup. Why?
It used to look like A, but now it looks like C for me and might look like B for you.

As far as I can tell, there's now no button anywhere to ignore a tag, and instead you have to go to the Ignored Tags box, click edit, and input its name there.

Another MSO post about the same experiment: New tag watch redesign uses the full wiki (without formatting) in the modal instead of using the tag wiki excerpt

it's actually even worse than you describe. Not only do you have to click into it you have to click again to get to the tag wiki.

@KevinB Oh, you're right, you can't do it like I thought. But I don't see an "Ignore tag" button in the wiki, do you? I edited to add how I was able to do it.

Yea, i don't see one there either. awesome. so the only place is the widget on the question list page.

This is by design per this Meta SE announcement: Upcoming sign-up experiments related to tags

Experiment 2: Updating the tag hover
We will be running an A/B/C test when users hover over tags. We intend to test whether simplifying the hover and making the call-to-action more evident will encourage more users to watch tags.

And this is probably related too:

Experiment 1: Understanding the reason users “Ignore tags”
We have a significant number of anonymous users who are clicking the ignore button on hover for questions. However, this action does nothing for that page, so we want to better understand why they are using it. [...]


Are people downvoting because they believe this doesn't answer the question, or because they don't like it? I can't remember how Meta works in that respect. If it's the first one, I would welcome feedback or an alternate answer. If it's the second one, don't shoot the messenger ;P go downvote the MSE post instead

Seconded. This is a good answer. I hate the policy, but @wjandrea provided a fact-based post, not an opinion on whether the policy is a good idea. I don't think "voting works differently here" is applicable in this particular case.

They want to "ignore" the popup. Otherwise it stays until you pass over it again.
